# Facing problem while trying to install texstudio in 18.04

Tags: apt, software-installation, dpkg

While trying to install texstudio through terminal it says one file is already there and it can't overwrite that file. I tried to delete that texstudio folder from `usr/share/texstudio` but its all hopeless.

```
Preparing to unpack .../texstudio_2.12.14-0~201811301519~ubuntu18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking texstudio (2.12.14-0~201811301519~ubuntu18.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/texstudio_2.12.14-0~201811301519~ubuntu18.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/texstudio/tabletemplate_fullyframed_firstBold.js', which is also in package texstudio-doc 2.12.6+debian-2
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/texstudio_2.12.14-0~201811301519~ubuntu18.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy texstudio texstudio-doc` to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Method 1: Reconfigure Package Database
The first method you can try is to reconfigure the package database. Probably the database got corrupted while installing a package. Reconfiguring often fixes the problem.

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Method 2: Use force install
If a package installation was interrupted previously, you may try to do a force install.

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

more methods: [link to itfoss.com](https://itsfoss.com/dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1/)